# Populate an array

Tags: c++, arrays, populate

I'm trying to populate an array with integers, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.
I'm writing a program that ask for the amount of pancakes each person has and im wanting to store each amount into an array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   //An array of people

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i ++)
    {
        int amount;
        cout<<"How many pancakes did person eat? \n";
        cin >> amount ;

        people[i] = amount;

    }
}
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: Anyway you should declare you amount var outside the for.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa why? It doesn't look like it's needed outside of the scope of the for loop, and its c++ ...

Comment: Infact I said that SHOULD, not MUST. IMO it's really a bad practice to declase this kind of vars inside a loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you program C++ you should use std::vector instead of normal arrays. The code might then look like this:

```
std::vector<int> people;
...
// Add amount at the end of the array
people.push_back(amount);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically create an integer array as follows:

```
int * people = new int[10]; // 10 is the number of elements inside the array
```

Or, it can statically be defined:

```
int people[10];
```

To compare the difference between them: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12755/